# Inserting values with a select subquery AND an additional variable

Tags: sql, pdo, subquery, prepared-statement

I have a query that updates a boolean value for a given record, then inserts that record into another table (depending on the action performed) using a select subquery. The select subquery is working fine, but how can I add an additional variable on to the end of the query to be inserted ? The reason why I need to do this is because the select subquery doesn't contain this data, and this data will only be stored in one of the two tables that the original record gets "copied" to.

```
$id = $_POST['id'];
$action = $_POST['action'];
$reason = $_POST['reason'];
if($action == "approve") {
    $statement = $db->prepare("UPDATE waiting SET wait = :status WHERE id = :id");
    $statement->bindValue(':status', 0);
    $statement->bindParam(':id', $id);
    $statement->execute();

    $statement = $db->prepare("INSERT INTO approved (fname, lname, student_id, email, type) SELECT fname, lname, student_id, email, type FROM waiting WHERE id = :id");
    $statement->bindParam(':id', $id);
    $statement->execute();
    $lastId = $db->lastInsertId();

    $statement = $db->prepare("UPDATE approved SET reason = :reason WHERE id = $lastId");
    $statement->bindParam(':reason', $reason);
    $statement->execute();
}
```

Basically I want to combine the insert query that uses a select subquery and the update query that updates the reason into one query. Is this syntactically possible?

EDIT: I should be more clear and state that the reason being passed is a string entered by a user into a text field. It's not a column or any other data in a table.

Thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can always select a constant, and the `reason` value is just that from the SQL viewpoint, so you can write the insert as:

```
INSERT INTO approved (fname, lname, student_id, email, type, reason) 
SELECT fname, lname, student_id, email, type, :reason 
FROM waiting WHERE id = :id
```

Just bind the params then and run the query, and that's it.

Comment: Won't that basically be telling the query to select whatever it is I bind to :reason? My main issue is that the original table from which the record is being copied from doesn't have a "reason" field at all (which also means it doesn't have the same number of columns either)

Comment: From the original code I guess that the reason is provided by the user (`$reason = $_POST['reason'];`), and that is what should be inserted into the database. Clarify if I'm wrong.

Comment: Yes, that is correct. Sorry, I was quick to jump and assume at what you posted was not what I was trying to do. Your query actually worked perfectly. Thanks!

Answer (score 4):

Bbasically you can add an arbitary value to your select by simply hard coding the value in the query. To make it eaier to read you can alias it to the columnanme with `'YOUR VALUE' as reason`

```
INSERT INTO approved (fname, lname, student_id, email, type, reason) 
SELECT fname, lname, student_id, email, type, '$reason' as reason
FROM waiting WHERE id = :id
```

However, you cant parameterize table or column names so you need to manually quote and escape the value into the query.

Comment: That will add a column name but the select won't have anything for that column.

Comment: @Vache: `$reason` should be the value he wants to insert not the column name. For example throw `SELECT 'a value' as a` in an sql client and see what is returned :-)

Comment: Thanks, this works perfectly! The one other question I have now is this: what is the difference between your answer and SWeko's answer? Both of the queries you suggested work fine. The only thing about SWeko's query that looks nice is that I can parameterize "reason" and not worry about SQL injection.

Comment: AHH i thought you couldnt parameterize in a `SELECT` part, only in `WHERE/IN/HAVING/etc.` IF you have tried it hsi way and it works then by all means use it as a param... much better that way!

Answer (score 0):

If there is a limited number of "reasons", you could have a separate `reasons` table and join in your `SELECT`

```
INSERT INTO approved (fname, lname, student_id, email, type, reason) 
  SELECT w.fname, w.lname, w.student_id, w.email, w.type, r.reason
    FROM waiting w, reasons r 
    WHERE w.id = :id and r.id = :reasonsid
```

Comment: Sorry, the reason is going to be whatever the user enters in (it's basically a text field). Good idea though :)